# How to sort "weekday, day" format using dataTable and jQuery with internationalization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable

I have a web app that uses globalize.js for globalization. I'm trying to sort a column that uses the following format: "Tuesday, 22" (en-US) or "Terça-Feira, 22" (pt-BR).

I used this block of code to test:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "weekdays-sort-pre": function (a) {
        return a.replace(/^.+,/, "");
    },

    "weekdays-sort-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "weekdays-sort-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

But it didn't sort correctly. Actually, the result i got you can see here:

[Screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tONAe.png)

Does anyone know how to ignore the first part (day of week) and use only the numbers to sort?

The result I want:

```
Sunday, 24
Friday, 29
Saturday, 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting plugin has two major problems :

1. It has two `desc` implementations
2. It does not return the number as actual `number`

Here is an improved version

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "weekdays-sort-pre": function (a) {
        return parseInt(a.replace(/^.+,/, ""))   //return number
    },
    "weekdays-sort-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "weekdays-sort-asc": function (a, b) {       //implement asc
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

And you must of course actually use the plugin (not totally clear from the question) :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
     { targets: [0], type: 'weekdays-sort'}
   ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kjjsdumc/**

The internationalisation-part is redundant since all you need is to extract a number from a string.

Comment: Thank you so much. In addition to what you gave to me, I had to update the plugin. I got it now.